# cross-conditional color formatting based on user input in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle12c

I am currently trying to add a feature to an existing Oracle Apex application (Apex). I have already looked around on here and found a few guides but none are helping me specifically with this subject and as I am a complete newbie to Oracle Apex, I am asking this question and thankful for any help:

how can I *cross-conditionally color format the text of a text-field* returned to the user (see link below) *based on another item on the page?* More or less like a succes/failure-message.

[highlighted succes/failure-message-text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoSzf.png)

The content from the success/failure-message is returned from a stored procedure, which is run after the user scans a barcode for input (:P1_CANN, text field, label: 'Scanneingabe'). After running, the stored procedure returns two values: the content of the success/failure-message (:P1_CANNBACK, display only page item) and a value 1/0 for scan/failure of the scan (:P1_CSS,hidden page item). *Based on the value returned from :P1_CSS I would like to color the text of the success/failure-message correspondingly,* for instance to green if the returned value is 1 and red if it is 0.

I am using Oracle 12c as the database. The stored procedure runs a short PL/SQL-Code:

```
 *#OWNER#.DOMENICO_SCANN_ENT(PSCANN => :P1_CANN, pr => :P1_CANNBACK, pr1 => :P1_CSS);*.
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using css. There are different ways you can implement this. One way is this:

1. Create a page item to contain the class name, eg P1_CANNBACK_CLASS
2. Create a computation to set the value of P1_CANNBACK_CLASS after you have called your stored procedure. PL/SQL code would be something like

```
CASE :P1_CANN WHEN 1 THEN 'u-success-text' WHEN 0 THEN 'u-danger-text' END
```

3. On Page Item P1_CANNBACK, set the css class to `&P1_CANNBACK_CLASS.`

[image]

Note that I used the apex provided css classes (documented here: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/color-and-status-modifiers). You can use your style, but then you'll have to define the css classes in the page properties or in a static file. I tested this on a 20.2 instance.

Comment: so I created a page item to contain the class name and called it _P1_CANNBACK_CSS_ (Step 1). Then, I created a computation by right-clicking _P1_CANNBACK_CSS_ and changed the point to _after regions_ as well as type to _pl/sql expression_ and added `case :P1_CSS
when 1 then 'u-danger-text'
when 0 then 'u-success-text' 
end` (Step 2). Where I got stuck, is Step 3 finding on page item P1_CANNBACK the place to set the CSS Class accordingly to `&P1_CANNBACK_CSS`. Is it maybe because my content body is _static content_?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer with the picture :) I am aware of the location to set the CSS Class within Page Item. When clicking on any of the page items named above, I do not find "CSS Classes" on Page Item but I found a workaround by changing to the _Component View_. There, I selected `P1_CANNBACK` and added `&P1_CANNBACK_CSS.` in _Column CSS Classes_. But I couldnot change the text-color of P1_CANNBACK when testing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll have to debug using the chrome developer tools to see why it is not being applied. If you put together an example on apex.oracle.com and give me access I can have a look for you.

Comment: Sure, I checked with my superior at work and because of security reasons I am not allowed letting you 'alone' on the workspace. Nevertheless, I have 2 suggestions for you helping me out; either we meet up virtually at the date&time of your choosing, I use MS-Teams-Meeting/Zoom or I could give you access to a workspace (on apex.oracle.com) where I import the application to but without the database connection. Afterwards, I would post the solution to this thread asap.  I guess, simply exporting the application and handing it to you would not help out.

Comment: I meant that you create a workspace on apex.oracle.com, the public oracle apex instance, under your own name. Create a reproducible case on the emp/dept tables

Comment: my bad, I will do this.