# Oracle Apex dynamically change success message color based on page item

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I'm using oracle apex version 22.2 and I'm trying to conditionally change the color of my pl/sql's success message based on a page item value. Basically if my process returns a '1' into my page item then I want the message to be green, if '0' then I need the message to be yellow. I tried accomplishing this with a DA set to occur after the page refresh. The javascript code shows as below.

```
var successMsg = document.querySelector('.t-Alert--success');
var colorValue = $v('P101_CHGCOLOR');
if (colorValue == '1') {
   successMsg.style.backgroundColor = '#4CAF50'; //set success color
   successMsg.style.color = '#FFFFFF';
} else if (colorValue == '0') {
   successMsg.style.backgroundColor = '#eed202'; //set warning color
   successMsg.style.color = '#000000';
}
```

Already attempted the solution here [cross-conditional color formatting based on user input in Oracle Apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65610192/cross-conditional-color-formatting-based-on-user-input-in-oracle-apex) but with no success. I'm not sure where in that solution we're actually supposed to tell apex to change the success message color.

Comment: Hope your Query will be solved by below link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66855414/oracle-apex-custom-success-message

Answer (score 1):

That post you are referring to is pretty different. It is about a class that is added to a page item. In your case, you're trying to modify a class on the success message.

Since 21.1, apex uses css variables. So you could create a dynamic action on page load that sets the css variable depending on the page item value with javascript. For example:

```
var r = document.querySelector(':root');
let alertColor;
alertColor = apex.item('P153_VALUES').getValue() == 1 ? 'green' : 'red'
r.style.setProperty('--ut-palette-success', alertColor);
apex.message.showPageSuccess( "Changes saved!" );
```

Note that that example the success message is executed from within javascript. With the default success message that is passed from another page, it will first show the original color and then change to the color that you defined and that doesn't look good. This example is just a very basic prototype (for example you'll still need to write some code to prevent it from firing on page load, but it could point you in the right direction

Comment: Trying to just get a starting point by seeing the color change. Regardless of my page item's value, the success message is green. The message itself changes to "Changes saved!" when my P153_VALUES = 0 so the js code is running.  I set the event to 'Page Load' and have no conditions applied. I know you said this is just a prototype but it seems like the `r.style.setProperty('--ut-palette-success', alertColor);` should be setting the color. Are there some other properties I need to be looking at?

Comment: Just tried this out in a new app, page 1. It worked. I tested on 23.1. The message was red because the page item P153_VALUES does't exist. Is this on universal theme or on of the older themes ? If it is universal theme, are you on the latest version ? What is the version of the compatibility mode of your app ?

Comment: Upvoted because you've confirmed that this does work. Not sure where my incompatibilities lie but I couldn't get the success message to change colors (although I did get the page item to change). A new parameter came up in my job request that allowed me to use `raise_application_error` instead of changing the success message's color. So i'm going with that for now, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **.addClass** method of jQuery.
First you need to create a class like this below code :

```
.green-alert {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

after that you can put this class name with using **.addClass** method like this below code :-

```js
var colorValue = $v('P101_CHGCOLOR');

if (colorValue == '1') {

   $('#P101_CHGCOLOR').addClass('green-alert');

} else if (colorValue == '0') {

   $('#P101_CHGCOLOR').addClass('warning-alert');
}
```